# Prevent data from being submitted in a form

Tags: laravel, forms, request, leaflet

I have a HTML form in my Laravel Blade view, with a leaflet map inside to show some data. The problem is, when I want to submit my form, this map is generating data and inserting it into the form, with the field name: "leaflet-base-layers_xx" where xx are random numbers that change everytime, so I can't just unset this data in my controller.

```
$data = $request->all();
unset($data['leaflet-base-layers_95']);
```

Is there any way I could prevent the map from submitting data. Or any way I could unset the field I want, knowing that it has a flexible name ?

Comment: you should post some codes for people to see and actually help out.

Comment: Can you `dd()` your data after the `$request->all()` . Post the response that you get.

Comment: With $request->all() you would be returned a collection. With collections you can do it like this : $data->forget('leaflet-base-layers_95');

Comment: I can't just forget one specific field as the name 'leaflet-base-layers_95' is auto-generated, it seems that it could also be 'leaflet-base-layers_86' or anything else, and it changes every time I submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be validating the request. This will not only validate the fields that you do want, but will also provide an easy way filter out any fields that you don't want or weren't expecting to receive.

For example, if your form should only have a title and body field

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

Now `$data` will now only contain 'title' and 'body', no matter what other fields were submitted.

If you take this a step further and use a Form Request you can use `$request->validated()` method which again will only contain the validated fields and none of the other garbage you don't want.

```
$data = $request->validated();
```

Aside from this solving your problem, as a matter of good practice you should always only ever work with validated data. Passing unvalidated data around your app is a recipe for disaster.

Refs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: I could do that, but the thing is i have 30+ fields, so specifying all of them in a validator just to say they're nullable (because they're not required) is a little too much I think...

Comment: Crikey. ANY application should validate all user input data properly even if this means you have to write 10,000 lines of code to do so. The fact that Laravel lets you do this so easily with a single array entry for each input is a blessing. Validate your data for goodness sake, and just enjoy the benefit that it also solves your problem.